# Can a current source provide Voltage to a resistor?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

We know that the tension between a perfect current source is 0

[image]

We have Va-Vb= 0 but we also have by ohm's law Va-Vb=RI=5V
so 5 = 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We know that the tension between a perfect current source is 0

That's a common misconception held by those first introduced to current sources.

In fact, an ideal current source produces a fixed current *regardless* of the voltage across.

Put another way, the voltage across an ideal current source is determined by the attached circuit which is, in this case, a resistor.

So, by Ohm's law,

$$V_A - V_B = 5V$$

and there is no contradiction.  The current is 5A *regardless* and the voltage across (and power delivered) is determined by the attached resistance.